# Не могу понять есть ли в SQL Express, SQL Agent

Tags: sql-server

В описаннии говорится что нету, а вот в мэнеджменте вижу вот такое -

[image: менеджмент]

Что там за Agent такой?
Агент необходим для запуска скриптов по расписанию.
Версия SQL Server Express 2014.

Answer (score 4):

У **экспресс** версии **нету** агента, точнее он то есть что б "подразнить" пользователей (шутка, скорее для совместимости), но реально он не доступен. Что б был доступен нужна лицензия.

Агент умеет выполнять sql-задания/скрипты по расписанию, разсылать почту. Но всё это можно сделать планировщиком или внешними примочками.

Нормальный sql-сервер с рабочим агентом доступен в некоторых версиях sqlserver 2005, его можно поискать в нете, но он не совместим с win7 и выше.

Comment: На сколько я помню MS сделал бесплатным SQL Server 2014 Developer Edition, в нем агент уж точно есть.